# what is the standard locale for Great Britain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization, locale

Specifically I'm trying to set up a countries model in my rails application that will contain the locale settings used by Rails i18n.

I have found conflicting information about how Great Britain is represented.

According to this source it is en-GB
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

But according to this source it is en-UK
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/i18n.html

is it GB or UK, or does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **should** be `GB` because the 2-letter country codes should correspond to those in ISO 3166 http://www.davros.org/misc/iso3166.html

I believe it is not uncommon to treat `UK` as an alias for `GB`, and as such support both.

Comment: UK is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Exceptional_reservations exceptionally reserved (by the UK) but I agree GB is the only correct one for common usage.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on Rails version. In 2.x it was `en-UK`, and then for Rails 3 it was [changed](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/57b65c0e253b289119825bee3f3c8d2e91de50a3/rails/locale/en-GB.yml) to `en-GB`.